# Checking if a value is in the RGB range and then increment/decrement

Tags: python, algorithm, python-3.x, pygame

Is there a better way to check if the variable `x` is in the 0-255 range and:

- if `x` is less than 255, add `colVel` to it
- if `x` equals 255 minus `colVel` from it.

My implementation, in Python 3.8.

```py
if 0 <= x < colVel:
    flag = True
if (255-colVel) < x < 255:
    x = 255        
if (255-colVel) <= x <= 255: 
    flag = False
if flag == True:
    x += colVel
if flag == False:
    x -= colVel
```

This section of code is a function that creates iridescence while an object moves. This is all of my code, and I'm happy for it to be reviewed.

```py
import pygame
import random
pygame.init()

win = pygame.display.set_mode((800,600))

pygame.display.set_caption('Chachi')
x = 50
y = 50
width = 2
height = 2
vel = 5
colVel = 10
rf = True
gf = True
bf = True
running = True

def irid(r, g, b, rFlag=True, gFlag=True, bFlag=True):
        def rgbRange(x, flag):                
                if 0<= x< colVel:
                        x = random.randint(1, 100) 
                        flag = True
                if (255-colVel) < x < 255:
                        x = 255        
                if (255-colVel) <= x <= 255: 
                        flag = False
                if flag==True:
                        x += colVel
                if flag==False:
                        x -= colVel   
                return x, flag        
        r, rFlag = rgbRange(r, rFlag)
        g, gFlag = rgbRange(g, gFlag)
        b, bFlag = rgbRange(b, bFlag)          
        return r, g, b, rFlag, gFlag, bFlag
r = irid(0, 255, 0)[0]
g = irid(0, 255, 0)[1]
b = irid(0, 255, 0)[2]
          
while running:
    pygame.time.delay(1)
    
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            running = False
    keys = pygame.key.get_pressed()
    
    if keys[pygame.K_LEFT]:
        x -= vel
        r, g, b, rf, gf, bf = irid(r, g, b, rf, gf, bf)
            
    if keys[pygame.K_RIGHT]: 
        x += vel
        r, g, b, rf, gf, bf = irid(r, g, b, rf, gf, bf)
    if keys[pygame.K_UP]:
        y -= vel
        r, g, b, rf, gf, bf = irid(r, g, b, rf, gf, bf)
    if keys[pygame.K_DOWN]:
        y += vel
        r, g, b, rf, gf, bf = irid(r, g, b, rf, gf, bf)
            
    pygame.draw.rect(win, (r, g, b), (x, y, width, height) )
    pygame.display.update()
    
pygame.quit()
```

[image: Image of all the code running]

Comment: Your specification is unclear and I don't think your implementation gets it right...

Comment: As for what section to review - it's up to a reviewer. I couldn't ask to review the whole code, as its too big to ask. If you can propose the better practice for the whole task - it would be only better. But as for my first section with 255 range checker I absolutely sure there is much more of a solution. Maybe I don't even need a function.

Comment: The amount of code above is quite small, so it's perfectly fine for you to ask for a review of all of it. :) If it fits in the question then you can ask us to review it all. If it doesn't fit in the question you can post multiple questions so we review all of it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

## Avoid repeating yourself

First, avoid having separate variables for `r`, `g` and `b`. It means you have to write all code three times. Just store the three components in a list, like so:

```
color = [0, 255, 0]
```

Then you can pass `color` to other functions, and have those functions iterate over the elements of the list.

## Better way to create a triangle wave

What you are doing is basically creating a [triangle wave](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Triangle_wave) shape for the intensity of each color component. Instead of keeping the current color value and a flag to store whether you are on the increasing slope or decreasing slope, just store a variable that holds the phase in a full cycle of the triangle wave.

In this case, I would store an integer between 0 and 511 for each color component. Initialize the phase like you did the color vector before:

```
phase = [0, 255, 0]
```

When updating the phase, do:

```
for i in range(3):
    phase[i] += colorVel
    phase[i] %= 512
```

Of course, this gives a sawtooth wave, and the values you get will be too high, but now you can map it onto a triangle wave with the correct amplitude:

```
color = list(map(lambda x: x if x < 256 else 511 - x, phase))
```

## Create a class to store the state of the iridescence

Even better would be to have a class manage all the internal state of an iridescence color, and allow it to be called as a function that generates the next color:

```
class Iridecence:
    def __init__(self, r, g, b, colVel=10):
        self.phase = [r, g, b]
        self.colVel = colVel

    def __call__(self):
        for i in range(3):
            if self.phase[i] < self.colVel:
                self.phase[i] = random.randint(1, 100)
            self.phase[i] += self.colVel
            self.phase[i] %= 512;
        return list(map(lambda x: x if x < 256 else 511 - x, self.phase))
```

Now you can use this as follow in your code:

```
irid = Iridescence(0, 255, 0)
color = irid()

while running:
    ...
    if keys[pygame.K_LEFT]:
        x -= vel
        color = irid()
    ...
    pygame.draw.rect(win, color, (x, y, width, height) )
    pygame.display.update()
```

Comment: a m a z i n g. Thank you very much!